# SharePoint 2010 project templates missing in Visual studio 2015 Enterprise Edition

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, visual-studio, windows-server, visual-studio-2015

On windows server 2012 we have installed Visual studio 2015 Enterprise Edition but unfortunately, I can't see the SharePoint 2010 project templates.

Can anyone help me out to get those templates? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick solution, try running:

```
devenv.exe /installvstemplates
```

From the RUN window.

If that doesn't work, try downloading and installing **[Office Developer Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx)**. It should include VS templates for SharePoint.

Failing that, you *may* need to uninstall/reinstall or repair visual studio.